# SonataNotificationBundle: Ejecutar comando en despliegue sobre amazon Beanstalk

Tags: symfony2, aws

Tengo una app hecha con Symfony y SonataNotificationBundle. Necesito en el despliegue de la app sobre amazon Beanstalk que se ejecute un comando para que se activen los consumidores que he hecho con sonataNotification.

Actualmente tengo dos archivos  en la carpeta .ebextensions:
composer.config
notifications.config

el composer.config funciona correctamente, el error lo he localizado en el notifications.config. Este solo tiene tres lineas:

```
commands:
  02execute_consumers:
    command: php app/console --env=prod sonata:notification:start
```

Beanstalk me devuelve este error en el despliegue:

```
[2017-06-13T05:48:05.389Z] INFO [7883] - [Application update aws-ffm-bgg34@43/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_PROYECTO/Command 02execute_consumers] : Activity execution failed, because: Could not open input file: app/console
(ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Lo que entiendo aqui es que el directorio donde se encuentra el entorno de despliegue no es el de la app, por lo cual no encuentra el archivo app/console.

En un equipo local, lo unico que tendria que hacer es ir al directorio de la aplicacion, y ejecutar ese mismo comando:

```
php app/console --env=prod sonata:notification:start
```

Como puedo hacer esto en Beanstalk? Cual seria el directorio? O me estoy olvidando de algo basico?

Answer (score 0):

Tras unos días dándole vueltas a este asunto, he encontrado una solución. He modificado el archivo en el que tengo el comando y pongo lo siguiente:

```
commands:
  10MigrationCommand:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && sudo php /var/www/html/app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=prod --no-interaction

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

En este caso, el archivo console esta en **/var/www/html/app/console**

NO HAY QUE OLVIDAR el **--env=prod**, ya que sino coje los datos de desarrollo (normalmente la bbdd en desarrollo hace referencia a localhost) y